# unzip command says file is corrupt but isn't. How to unzip on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, unzip

I have a large zip file which I need to unzip on ubuntu. (~6GB)

The standard `unzip` command fails, saying the file is corrupt. This happens on both OSX and Ubuntu.

I can successfully unzip the file by a) double-clicking with finder on osx b) `ditto -V -x -k --rsrc myfile.zip .` on the command line on osx.

Any ideas for how I can get this unziped this on ubuntu? And any ideas what the underlying issue is?

The error message when running `unzip` on both OSX and Ubuntu is:

> Archive:  myfile.zip warning [myfile.zip]:  1768583893 extra bytes at
>   beginning or within zipfile   (attempting to process anyway) error
>   [myfile.zip]:  start of central directory not found;   zipfile
>   corrupt.   (please check that you have transferred or created the
>   zipfile in the   appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled
>   UnZip properly)

Edit: Surprisingly unzip seems to be very unstable for large files! Java did the trick. Many others with the same issue:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/235139/how-to-unzip-files-bigger-than-4gb/434537
- https://serverfault.com/questions/530114/are-there-other-options-to-unzip-a-file-in-ubuntu-besides-unzip?rq=1

Comment: can you post a hexdump of the first 512 bytes or so? do `hexdump -C myfile.zip | head -n 32`

Comment: @AlfredRossi Unfortunately the file is a little too sensitive to post anything here. Also, I was able to use the java workaround mentioned below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you've got Java on the box, you can use :

```
jar xf test.zip
```

For more info look at https://serverfault.com/questions/235139/how-to-unzip-files-bigger-than-4gb/434537

Comment: Why the heck was this necessary. Really annoying.